# Drools setup in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, drools

I having trouble on the setup of drools I already tried [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch08.html) to setup my drools and it seems doesn't work for me then what i tried next is to go to marketplace and install the plugin from there, from there I'm able to open the perspective that means i already install the plugin on my eclipse.

Not I'm trying to create a drool project to see the example included to the project but the project doesn't have the **Drool Library**

That also make the **imports** to error, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial, [chapter 8.2](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e7865), normally the Drools plugin would add the Drools library to your new rule project.
If that doesn't work, you can always add the Drools library to the build path of your project via Eclipse.  Right click on your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> tab Libraries -> Add library (or add external jar and add the Drools.jar's manuallly)